# State Monads - In Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to create a calculator with an integer state which allows the user to update this state using commands. This is what I've got so far.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import Control.Monad.Except
import Control.Monad.State


data CalcCmd = EnterC
         | StoreC Int CalcCmd
         | AddC Int CalcCmd
         | MultC Int CalcCmd
         | DivC Int CalcCmd
         | SubC Int CalcCmd


run :: (MonadState Int m, MonadError String m) => CalcCmd -> m ()
run (EnterC) = return()

run (StoreC a b) = do
                  put (a)
                  run b

run (AddC a b) = do
                modify((+) a)
                run b

run (MultC a b) = do
                modify((*) a)
                run b

run (DivC a b) = do
                modify ((div) a)
                run b

run (SubC a b) = do
                modify((-) a)
                run b
```

No matter what the commands are, the state always ends up as 0. For example, Both "StoreC 7 (EnterC)" and "StoreC 7 (AddC 14 (DivC 3 EnterC))" give the state back as 0. What am I doing wrong?

The textbook says The StoreC command should manually update the state And the EnterC command should terminate the calculation, returning the unit type.

Also When using state monads, is there a few things which I should be doing no matter what the function is about?

Here's the output. [image]

Comment: How are you running this?

Comment: The code you posted looks fine. The issue is elsewhere. Post the rest of the code, including how you are using `run` to test it. Which specific monad `m` are you using in your tests? If that's user-defined maybe it has a bug. It's hard to tell without the full code.

Comment: Is the  `MonadError` constraint really necessary for this question? `run` doesn't make use of it at all.

Comment: MonadError was for a further requirement but it's unnecessary here, I've updated the code with the output

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Post the transcript as text.

Comment: *Both "StoreC 7 (EnterC)" and "StoreC 7 (AddC 14 (DivC 3 EnterC))" give the state back as 0* This is not what I'm getting. The first commag returns 7 as the state. The second command returns 0 simply because `div 3 21` is 0.

Comment: command 1 is not 7, it's 0. And I don't know why.

Comment: Ok so I looked in the textbook and it uses 'div' rather then (div), is there any reason why?

Comment: Note that your type is more complicated than necessary. Each CalcCmd other than EnterC contains exactly one Int, exactly one other CalcCmd, and a tag. So it's really the same as a list of pairs of tags and ints: `data Command = Add | Sub | ... ; type Program = [(Command, Int)]` (with the `Enter` at the end implicit).

Answer (score 1):

Could not reproduce. `runStateT (run cmd3 :: CS ()) (0 :: Int)` returns `Right ((), 7)` here. (The others do return `0`, because `div 3 ((+) 14 7) = div 3 21 = 0` and `div 0 ((*) 2 10) = div 0 20 = 0`. In other words, your `State` monad is doing the calculation you asked it to do, so your misunderstanding, whatever it is, probably is not related to state monads.)

Are you double-plus sure you are loading the file you saved? Is it possible you're saving to a different directory than you are loading from, e.g.? Or perhaps forgot to press save (I've seen it happen even to professionals...)?